# Getting Blank Page after submit Login in WSO2 with LDAP

Tags: authentication, wso2, ldap, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

I have problem with the login to MyAccount/Console using the LDAP user store that I have already created. I have already changed my Resident Identity Provider to my custom hostname, I'm not sure if there's any more setting that I need to do in deployment.toml, but if I change the [User Store] in deployment.toml then it will have issue opening even the https://domainname:9443/carbon.[this is after click on login button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifzve.png)

Any problem that I have found in the inspect side is the Token error parts but at the bottom part there's another Token that is not error.
[Token Error & another Token that have no error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8orsp.png)

Here is my Resident IPs
[Resident Identity Providers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oJ73.png)

Here is my LDAP setting
[LDAP setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIvz2.png)

Here is my Deployment.toml
[Deployment.toml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGjJG.png)

Using WSO2 6.1.0
Oracle Linux 8.8 as WSO2 server
389DS for LDAP

I'm still trying to solve the loading issues, do please help if there's any idea what I might have done wrong.

I can see my LDAP is correct, since I try to login with the account I have created is 389DS LDA, and wso2 log can get the Email, Username, First Name, Last Name & etc.

Comment: can you remove the port number (`:9443`) from home realm identifier in the resident identity provider and try again?